# Pricing optimisation when elasticities are positives?

Tags: optimization, elasticity

I’m performing some exercises in order to get the optimal price of some product such a potato chips, biscuits, drinks, etc. (I’m taking price per unit and sales in units) But I’ve found that some of them have positive elasticities. This can makes sense for me, as if some biscuits brand is not so successful (in sales), price can decrease in order to be more attractive and on the other hand, I you have increase in demand, you can growth your price. But under this scenario, how can I establish an optimal price? I’m using a log-log model to obtain elasticities.
Also, at this scenario taking into account cross-elasticities would make sense? By example, how can biscuits influence chips’ sales?

Comment: A positive [price elasticity of demand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_elasticity_of_demand) essentially means that demand increases with increasing price. I don't quite understand your argument for why this makes sense to you. And price optimization is very easy in this case, simply increase the price without bounds, you will make unlimited profit (until constrained by supply)! That already shows you that something is broken. At the very least, you need to model an elasticity that differs by price, so at some point, it *does* become negative. ...

Comment: ... And to be honest, positive elasticities are so rare that if you observe them, it's far more likely that you are falling prey to the variance in your estimations than that you found a true positive elasticity. I'd much rather constrain my elasticities to be nonpositive. The error I'm introducing here (bias!) is likely much less serious than trying to make sense of a spurious positive elasticity (variance!).